# Disable color output in react-scripts test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, continuous-integration, react-scripts

Is there a way to disable colorized output for tests run via `react-scripts test`? I'd like to disable this to get rid of the color control codes in our CI pipeline.

With jest you can specify `jest --no-colors`, but `react-scripts test --no-colors` does not seem to pass the option down to jest.

FYI, the app was created with `create-react-app` and the react version is 17.0.0.

Comment: I think it's using https://github.com/chalk/supports-color under the hood, so setting the `FORCE_COLOR=0` env var should work

Comment: That said, FWIW `npm test -- --watchAll=false --no-colors` in a clean CRA app, which runs `react-scripts test "--watchAll=false" "--no-colors"`, does disable the colours. `FORCE_COLOR=0 npm test -- --watchAll=false` did too, as did using `CI=true npm test` (which should be set in your pipeline already).

Answer (score 2):

"env FORCE_COLOR=0" worked for me.

Neither "npm config set color false" nor "npm --no-color" worked, though.

Comment: Wow, I actually had the opposite problem, having colored text when using jest and not when using react-scripts, adding `FORCE_COLOR=true` in my `.env` file did the trick ! Thanks for mentioning the variable !

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the proposed solutions worked for me. ("react-scripts": "5.0.0")

My solution for this was installing as dev dep
"@relmify/jest-serializer-strip-ansi"
and in package.json have this

```
"jest": {
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "@relmify/jest-serializer-strip-ansi/always"
]
```

},

List of supported jest config overwrites for CRA
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#configuration